# auto.arima prediction

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, accuracy

I have this time series of call volume of a contact center. It is composed of 15565 points where every 48 points represents one day. I used 12960 points as training set for the auto.arima model. According to the testing below

> ### maximum number of non-seasonal differences allowed
>
> ndiffs(TS, alpha=0.05, test=c("kpss","adf", "pp"), max.d=2)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzIK9.jpg) 0
>
> ### maximum number of seasonal differences allowed
>
> nsdiffs(TS, m=frequency(TS), test=c("ocsb","ch"), max.D=2)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzIK9.jpg) 0

there is no need for seasonal or non-seasonal differencing although the auto.arima do the differencing automatically if required. However, the accuracy of the 5 day ahead forecast is poor as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Consider using `r` tag as you relate to R `forecast` library (this is also worth mentioning).

Comment: Assuming that the 48 points in each day are recorded at regular intervals, you have half-hourly data. For this kind of high-frequency data, exponential smoothing as implemented in function `tbats` of the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) package may be a better alternative to an ARIMA model.

Comment: Post your data to dropbox.com. Specify which country the data is for so we can account for holidays. Provide any causals that explain any variability in the data.  Specify the beginning date so that the holidays can be synced up.

Comment: In my experience, `auto.arima` performs worse than a model you would fit after performing some EDA on your data